# Javascript Number Ending In Zero

Tags: javascript

I need a Number object with the exact value:

1.0 (and NOT "1.0" since I don't want a String object but a Number object)

but this doesn't work:

```
parseFloat('1.0')
```

Comment: What's wrong with `var x = 1.0;`? How exactly does your `parseFloat` line "not work"?

Comment: Define "doesn't work". And what's wrong with just using `1.0`?

Comment: try `parseFloat('1.0').toFixed(1);`

Comment: @NaNpx Not really a number at that point.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter "1.0" isn't fractional.

Comment: You guys, it's clearly just `1..toFixed(1)`, because javascript is awesome.

Comment: I don't want a string

Comment: this value will be passed in a JSON to be interpreted in Ruby which recognizes the number 1.0

Comment: @MattDiamant But that's a string. OP is just confused.

Comment: well I'd like an answer to my precise question, lol

Comment: @DaveNewton I know, I just put that there to point out a weird javascript quirk, allowing you to use dot syntax on numbers.

Comment: @MattDiamant Not that weird, any OOPL with reasonable syntax will let you chain methods off of objects.

Comment: @DaveNewton Yes, but not all OOPLs will let you do it with object literals, and definitely under a different set of rules than javascript. In javascript you can't do `1.toFixed(2)`, it will throw an error, most likely because it thinks you are trying to declare a floating point number. But, you can do `1.0.toFixed(2)`, because it's already a floating point number. And since in javascript `1. === 1.0`, you can do `1..toFixed(2)`.

Comment: @MattDiamant I'm saying it's not really a quirk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going about this the wrong way. Instead of trying to cast `1` as a float in javascript (which you CAN'T do), you should cast the JSON number `1` or the string `"1.0"` as a float in Ruby when you parse the JSON.

Comment: `1` *is* a float in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to work for me:

```
parseFloat('1.0');
```

Outputs:

1

Which is equal to 1.0 and 1.00 and 1.000 and 1.0000 (an so on). It all just depends on how you output the number to string format. I'm guessing you want something like:

```
var a = 1;
a.toFixed(1); // outputs "1.0"
```

Comment: I guess OP wants `1.0` as the output

Comment: exactly.. as stated. because this value will be passed in a JSON to be interpreted in Ruby which recognizes the number 1.0

Comment: and as stated I want a Number, not a String.

Comment: @user1943231 - Again, 1 == 1.0 in JavaScript. Therefore using the result to generate JSON will result in 1. If you want more control over the JSON format, you'll need to generate the JSON string yourself.

Comment: then your answer should be "it's impossible."

Comment: @user1943231 - If your actual question involved the Ruby details, then possibly. But your question specifically states that `parseFloat` doesn't work when, in fact, it works perfectly.

Comment: what if I can't generate the JSON string myself (i.e. don't want to mess with a module that's generating the json)

Comment: my question doesn't state that, lol, can you paste the part that does?

Comment: 1) You just edited your question. 2) You're still missing that mathematically, 1 == 1.0 so JavaScript is still giving you something that is EXACTLY 1.0. It just doesn't look the way you want it.